# Search for specific word and replace word next to it in a text file using php

Tags: php

I'm very new in php, please treat me as beginners. I am working on project which require changes in a Text file by php. I have a text file with some text like below:

user_name=400

user_domain=10.10.10.1

user_display=400

user_organization=

auth_name=400

auth_pass=0987poiu

I need to replace the some specific data of specific search only. Means  want to search word "user_name" and replace data next to it "400" and it should not replace any other line.

Is it possible by php code??

Please help me if it can.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you need this done in php, why add html and jquery tag? Also please show us what you have tried

Comment: Please do follow what @CarstenLøvboAndersen said and dont forget to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), but I will move on for the answer. So, question is: Does you file always have `user_name=` and then a number or whatever?

Comment: I apologies for wrong tag. @CarstenLøvboAndersen.

Comment: Yes, file always have data before "=". Only data after "=" need to be replace. @PeriklisKakarakidis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//instead of this, load data into the $str (file_get_contents, ...)
$str = 'user_name=400

user_domain=10.10.10.1

user_organization=

auth_name=400

auth_pass=0987poiu
';

$key = 'user_display'; //key to find
$value = 500; //value to set

$replaces = 0; //to store whether key was found and replaced in the string, remove if you don't need to add new keys

/*
 * try to find 
 * ^ means start of line
 * then $key=
 * .* means anything or nothing
 * $ means end of line
 * m says to process string as multiline
 */
$newstr = preg_replace('/^'.$key.'=.*$/m', $key.'='.$value, $str, 1, $replaces); //if you don't need to add new keys, remove ', 1, $replaces'

//if key is not in the file, add a new item, remove those line, if you don't need to add new keys
if ( $replaces === 0) { 
    $newstr = $str.PHP_EOL.$key.'='.$value.PHP_EOL;
}

//instead of echo, write file (file_put_contents, ...)
echo $newstr;
```